# Example of a process that is 2nd order stationary but not strictly stationary

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity

Does anybody have a nice example of a stochastic process that is 2nd-order stationary, but is not strictly stationary?

Comment: See also [If a time series is second order stationary, does this imply it is strictly stationary?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/119845/22228)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take any process $(X_t)_t$ with independent components that has a constant first and second moment and put a varying third moment.

It is second order stationnary because $E[ X_t X_{t+h} ]=0$ and it is not strictly stationnary 
because $P( X_t \geq x_t, X_{t+1} \geq  x_{t+1})$ depends upon $t$

Comment: Perhaps I am a little confused, or we are using different definitions?  Am I correct in thinking that a process is 2nd order stationary if the joint marginal cdfs
$F_{X(t),X(t+τ)}$ are equal for all $\tau$?

Similarly for a process to be 1st-order stationary the marginal cdfs $F_{X(t)}$ need to be the same for every $t$. So all the moments of the $X(t)$ must be equal. 

2nd-order stationary implies 1st-order stationary, correct?

Comment: Extending this, a process is $N$th order stationary if for every $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_N$ the marginal cdfs $F_{X(t_1 + \tau), X(t_2 + \tau)\dots,X(t_N+\tau)}$ are the same for all $\tau$.

Strictly stationary is Nth order stationary for all N.

Comment: see http://www.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/public/dutt/vorles/geost_03/node49.html for order 2 stationnarity. Anyway, I have tryed to clarify my answer, hope it is better now...

Comment: I believe that article describes stationary in the weak sense and this is not what I meant. I should clarify this in the question. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process for a description of the various types of stationarity.

Comment: @robby OK... I didn't know this "second order stationnarity" I think you should not say second order stationnarity in the question and give the definintion instead. For more clarity you should ask another question. do you have a paper that refers to this second order stationnarity ?

Comment: I'll put a second question together that better describes what I mean.  In the mean time, your answer is correct for the question I stated!

Comment: Why is the autocorrelation $E[X_tX_{t+h}] = 0$?