# What is a second order stationary process?

Tags: time-series

I was wondering how his "second-order stationary process" is defined in Brockwell and Davis' [Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting](http://books.google.com/books?id=VHB4OSAmwcUC&lpg=PA51&dq=.%20In%20fact,%20every%20second-order%20stationary%20process%20is%20either%20a%20linear&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The class of linear time series models, which includes the class of autoregressive
>   moving-average (ARMA) models, provides a general framework for studying stationary processes. In fact, every **second-order stationary process** is either a linear
>   process or can be transformed to a linear process by subtracting a deterministic com-
>   ponent. This result is known as Wold's decomposition and is discussed in Section 2.6.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Second-order_stationarity),

> The case of second-order stationarity arises when the requirements of strict stationarity are only applied to pairs of random variables from the time-series.

But I think the book has a different definition from Wikipedia's, because the book uses stationarity short for wide-sense stationarity, while Wikipedia uses stationarity short for strict stationarity.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: This is a good explanation by example:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/example-of-a-2nd-order-stationary-but-not-strictly-stationary-process Hope this helps, AO

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There can be some confusion of terms here depending on whether the adjective *seond-order*
is considered to be modifying *stationary* or *random process* (or both!).
To some people,

- A *second-order* random process $\{X_t \colon t \in \mathbb T\}$ is one for which
  $E[X_t^2]$ is finite (indeed bounded)
  for all $t \in \mathbb T$. For us electrical engineers who
  apply (or mis-apply!) random process models in studying electrical signals, $E[X_t^2]$
  is a measure of the average power delivered at time $t$ by a stochastic 
  signal, and so all physically observable signals are modeled as second-order
  processes.  Note that stationarity has not been mentioned at all
  and these second-order processes might or might not be stationary.
- A random process that is stationary to order $2$, which we can 
  (but perhaps should not) call
  a second-order stationary random process provided we agree that *second-order* modifies
  *stationary* and not *random process*, is one for which $\mathbb T$ is a set
  of real numbers that is closed under addition, and the joint distribution of
  the random variables $X_t$ and $X_{t+\tau}$ (where $t, \tau \in \mathbb T)$ depends
  on $\tau$ but not on $t$.  As the link provided by AO shows, a random
  process stationary to order $2$ need not be strictly stationary.  Nor is
  such a process necessarily *wide-sense-stationary* because there is no
  guarantee that $E[X_t^2]$ is finite: consider for example a strictly
  stationary process in which the the $X_t$'s are independent Cauchy random variables.
- A second-order random process (meaning finite power as in the first item above)
  that is stationary to *at least* order $2$ is wide-sense-stationary.

OK, so that is the perspective from a different set of users of
random process theory.  For more details, see, for example,
[this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235) on dsp.SE.

Comment: Why is $E[X_t^2]$ finite a requirement of wide-sense-stationary but not second order stationary? Can you provide a source for this constraint?

Comment: Stationary to order 2 says nothing about the _moments_ of the random variables, only about the distributions whereas wide-sense-stationarity is all about the moments and does not require any special properties of the distributions. The most commonly accepted _definition_ of wide-sense-stationarity includes the requirement of finite second moment but if you don't like it, you can discard the requirement and try to persuade others to accept your broader definition as the commonly accepted definition.

Comment: I ask because [Metrics' comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65353/what-is-a-second-order-stationary-process/65359?noredirect=1#comment126201_65358) below disagrees with you here. So your definition of a WSS process is a subset of "random processes of order 2 that are stationary to order 2"?

Comment: No, a second-order process (aka finite second moment) that is stationary to order 2 (or more) is a WSS process but stationarity to order 2 is _not_ necessary for a finite-second-moment process to be a WSS process. In other words, my definition of WSS processes includes stationary-to-order-2 processes that have finite second moment.

Answer (score 1):

Second order stationary is a weak stationary or covariance stationary. See the following excerpt from Time Series Analysis, J. Hamilton (1994) p. 108

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is second order stationarity same as wide-sense stationarity?

Comment: Yes @Tim. You can check that on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) too.

Comment: Surprising ...Wiki has separate definitions for weak and second order but there is no reference for second order stationary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing its the same as "weakly stationary". That means that $(x_k,\dots,x_{k-l})$ all (for all $k$, and any $l)$ have the same expectation and covariance matrix but not necessarily the same distribution.